# How do I use a udev file to rebind keys on a secondary keyboard that I intend to use for macros to execute a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to rebind the keys on a second keyboard in such a way that, when I press, say, the "A" key, it will trigger a script that will execute a command to write the letter `a` to a text file, then press the F24 key, which a different script is listening for which looks at the text file to see what information is in the file, then executing a command based on the information which is in the file, via a udev file.

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN0nbdFLsgw) to figure out how to do this, and I have created a udev file that looks something like this (this is paraphrased, because the actual file is really long:)

```
evdev:input:b*vYYYYpXXXXe*

#q
KEYBOARD_KEY_70014
#w
KEYBOARD_KEY_7001a
#e
KEYBOARD_KEY_70008
```

and the rest.

According to the tutorial, I should be able to rebind the keys to other keys, such as F16, F19, etc., but then I would run out of keys, since I intend to do this process to as many keys as possible; instead, what I want is to rebind the keys to scripts that do as spoken above.

Is it possible for this to be done?

Comment: When you say `F24` key do you mean something like the `PF24` key on IBM 3270 terminals / PCs used with AS/400's and mainframes? Or do you simply mean `Shift`+`F12` = `F24`?

Comment: While most keyboards only show F1-F12, most of those actually have 24 function keys; however, half of these are hidden.

Comment: That tutorial shows how to change the scancode->keycode binding. There is only a limited number of keycodes available, as you already found out. There is no way to bind scancodes to scripts. You can use the `BTN_*` keycodes which will give you some more keys, but that's the most you can get out of that method. I'm not sure if you can easily use buttons as shortcuts, though.

Comment: Ah.  Is there any other way I could achieve a similar effect?

Comment: If you are familiar with python, there is a module called `python-evdev` that could be used to grab a specific input device and listen to its input events. A small python application could then execute arbitrary commands based on the key that was pressed. However, if you only need one macro keyboard, there should be enough keycodes. There are more than 250 `KEY_*`  keycodes available plus a fair number of `BTN_` keycodes, so there should be enough for two 105 key keyboards.

Comment: Okay.  I will try to use `python-evdev`.  I'm not sure I'll stick with my original approach, though—it seems that it might be intercomunicador things.

Comment: @Blue-ManedHawk how did you go with this?

Comment: egggggggggggggg